# Nupic : RegionTest fails, pynode cannot be found

Tags: nupic

I built nupic as per the instructions in the wiki. However, when I run testeverything, the RegionTest fails with a message that pynode cannot be found since neither nta_rootdir nor pythonpath are set.

echo $pythonpath and echo $nta_rootdir gives the correct results though

The exact message is

```
MSG: Unable to find the pynode dynamic library because neither NTA_ROOTDIR not PYTHONPATH is set.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to track this issue on the [NuPIC issue tracker](https://github.com/numenta/nupic/issues/524).

Comment: Issue fixed through issue tracker.
The link :

  [1]: https://github.com/numenta/nupic/wiki/Installing-NuPIC-on-Ubuntu

The problem was with the pip install. Full explanation available at the link. Tested on linux mint 15 KDE (based on ubuntu 13.04)